# Laravel: Disable "Booked" times from time range

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to disable a box within a range of times throughout the day.

The day starts with an Employee's set day/time range, so for example, if the employee works on a Tuesday, 9-5 and a service which is 1 hour long, their last booking is 4pm as that is the last working hour slot for a booking. This logic works fine, however it's inserting the 'booked' slots within the day that I'm struggling with.

```
@php
$employee_booking = $bookings->where('employee_id',$employeedetails->id)->where('start_date', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['booking_date'])))->all();
@endphp

@for ($i=$start_time;$i<=$end_time;$i = $i + 30*60)
    @foreach($employee_booking as $booking)
        @if($i >= strtotime($booking->start_time) && $i <= strtotime($booking->end_time))
            Booking [unavailable] {{ $booking->start_time }} - {{ $booking->end_time }} ({{$booking->title}}) <br>
        @else
            {{ date('H:i a', $i) }} [available] <br>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endfor
```

In the example above, it's based on the employee's working hours pulling from the database specified as: 8am - 4pm. Please see this screenshot (list very long to add to thread): http://prntscr.com/k9e9b2

As you can see from the outputted data, they are repeating the times because it's in a foreach loop but I'm not sure of any other way to get this data to work.

The purpose of this data is to be fashioned into something more presentable, like so: http://prntscr.com/k9e9pp - As you can see from this example, the booking that's unavailable has been blocked out, this needs to be repeated to all other bookings for that day, not just the one for that example.

I'm assuming it has to go into an array and then somehow pulled through but it's this step that I'm really struggling with.

I hope this is enough information for someone to help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Matt

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql, and then try to figure out how to feed that into my code.

Comment: @Strawberry Hi, I've already got data back from the SQL and that's what my question is outlining. How do I get it to display into my code?

Comment: Your query (if I understand it) simply returns bookings for a given employee whose booking start dates coincide with a given date. So presumably, a service never lasts more than a single day?

Comment: @Strawberry That's correct. Let's say a service is 1 hour long, the employee has a 7 hour day and has 2 booking at 9am and 10am. 9am & 10am should be "disabled" in the view to the customer on the front-end but should show all other available times up until the cutoff of that employees day, which in this scenario is 1 hour before the users "end of day" time.

Comment: Employees and users are the same thing?

Comment: Sorry, yeah in my previous comment 'users' was in reference to 'employee'