# Display 9am-5pm in 30 minute blocks + array to cross out 'unavailable' times

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

This post is with reference to: [Laravel: Disable "Booked" times from time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51461134/laravel-disable-booked-times-from-time-range)

I need to display a list of times from 9am to 5pm in 30 minute blocks. I then need to block out a set amount of times. For example, if 12:30pm - 1:30pm was unavailable, I would need to have a strikethrough on the time.

The "unavailable times" need to be in an array as there may be multiple on any given day.

```
@php
$bookings_array = array(
    array(
        'start_time' => "09:00:00",
        'end_time'   => "10:00:00"
    )
)
@endphp

@for ($i=$start_time;$i<=$end_time;$i = $i + 30*60)
    @if($i >= strtotime($empbooking->start_time) && $i <= strtotime($empbooking->end_time))
        @foreach($employee_booking as $booking)
            Booking [unavailable] {{ $booking->start_time }} - {{ $booking->end_time }} ({{ $booking->title }}) <br>
        @endforeach
    @endif
    {{ date('H:i a', $i) }} [available] <br>
@endfor
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @Devon As my opening sentence stated, this is with reference to already previous code submitted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51461134/laravel-disable-booked-times-from-time-range. On this post I have explained the days generated, I'm trying to find a "simplified" version I can adapt to my requirements on the aforementioned post.

Comment: Read the how to ask section.  You shouldn't reference code elsewhere and you need to present an example of what you've done and why it isn't working.

Comment: @Devon Apologies, please see the edited version with code sample added. I've setup the array but I'm struggling to understand how to implement that to the rest of the code without duplicating times/bookings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't understand exactly what each variable in your code means, but I believe what you are looking for is something like this:

```
@php
    $bookings_array = array(
        (object)array(
            'start_time' => "12:30:00",
            'end_time'   => "13:30:00"
        ),
        (object)array(
            'start_time' => "16:30:00",
            'end_time'   => "18:00:00"
        )
    );

    $start_time = strtotime('09:00:00');
    $end_time = strtotime('19:00:00');
@endphp

@for ($i=$start_time;$i<=$end_time;$i = $i + 30*60)
    @foreach ($bookings_array as $booking)
        @if (strtotime($booking->start_time) <= $i && strtotime($booking->end_time) >= $i)
            {{ date('H:i a', $i) }} [unavailable] <br>
            @continue(2)
        @endif
    @endforeach
    {{ date('H:i a', $i) }} [available] <br>
@endfor
```

This solution sort of works, but it is kind of slow, cause you are iterating over the bookings array every time. A more efficient way would be to calculate the available/unavailable times beforehand and render after.

Comment: Thiago, that's spot on thank you works a treat! Just one more thing, how can I now  get my string to an array? Say for example: `$booking_array = $bookings->where('employee_id',$employeedetails->id)->where('start_date', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['booking_date'])))->get();` - would that work?

Comment: @MattyClarke in this case `$booking_array` will be a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections), but it should work without any changes. Just a note that you are filtering by the field `start_date` by the exact value. Perhaps you wanted to filter with `->where('start_date', '>', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['booking_date']))`?

Comment: That's perfect, works a treat. And it's correct, I have to match the booking to the exact date. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Thiago for the answer. My full code below that works as I wanted:

```
@php
            $employee_booking = $bookings->where('employee_id',$employeedetails->id)->where('start_date', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['booking_date'])))->all();
            @endphp
            @for ($i=$start_time;$i<=$end_time;$i = $i + 30*60)
                @foreach ($employee_booking as $booking)
                    @if (strtotime($booking->start_time) <= $i && strtotime($booking->end_time) >= $i)
                        <div>
                          <input type="radio" id="control_{{ date('H:i a',$i) }}" name="booking_time" value="{{ date('H:i a',$i) }}" disabled="disabled">
                          <label for="control_{{ date('H:i a',$i) }}">
                            <h2>{{ date('H:i a', $i) }}</h2> <!-- TAKEN DATE -->
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        @continue(2)
                    @endif
                @endforeach
                <div>
                  <input type="radio" id="control_{{ date('H:i a',$i) }}" name="booking_time" value="{{ date('H:i a',$i) }}">
                  <label for="control_{{ date('H:i a',$i) }}">
                    <h2>{{ date('H:i a',$i) }}</h2> <!-- AVAILABLE DATE -->
                  </label>
                </div>
            @endfor
```